# InfoPath Workflow; GroupID, Error Message: Group cannot be found

Tags: workflow, infopath, error, groups

I have created an InfoPath form workflow in designer. It is a simple workflow which uses the "Collect data from user" task. It requires that the user supply a choice: "Approve" or "Reject", and select a person using a group\people picker.

The workflow executed fine for the first day or so, but now is failing after the first task.

It returns a System\Administrator error to the workflow progress page, but is very under descriptive in the issue.

In the log we found:

> Failed to get SPGroupName from GroupID. Error Message: Group cannot be
>   found.  Callstack:    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPGroupCollection.GetByID(Int32 id)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.PeopleEditor.set_SharePointGroupID(Int32
>   value).

I have run a search for this on the web and have returned a lot of similar results but no solution.

Any Ideas? Similar Situations? Work abounds etc.?

Comment: I also have this issue whenever I open up a custom InfoPath 2010 form running in SP2013.  I have 24 contact objects on the form and i get this exact error 24 times whenever I open this form.  There is nothing special concerning the contact object.  It doesn't reference any odd url and everything in the contact object is default.  So what gives?  Any ideas?

Comment: Same error here. Complex info Path form with cannot be saved. I'm stuck

Answer (score 1):

I think you had this error because of the group/people picker properties are not same on InfoPath and SharePointDesigner. Check both of them and ensure that they are exactly the same. For example, I guess, people picker column in InfoPath allows multiple selection but in SharePointDesigner it does not.

Answer (score 0):

I had also faced this issue earlier. The form requires multiple approval and I was capturing the different approver inside infopath form. The issue was coming when I was taking the display name of the approver. The issue got away when i tried taking accountId of the approver. Hope this solve ur problem.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the solution is (2) steps:
First, in the Group Settings, set the applicable Permission Group (for example: "Can Submit a GCR") to ("Who can view the membership of the group?") to Everyone...
Then, republish the form so that the settings are pushed out to the form.

CORRECTION:
In my case the form was erroring out because on Form Load I attempt to set a People Picker field to userName() but the column setting for that field was set to a SP Group and that SP group only contained DOMAIN\all domain users. So it was simply not seeing/selecting the individual accounts.

THE SOLUTION:
I set the List column to All Users THEN I needed to update the settings on the field in InfoPath manually (it does not update automatically) for each view where the field is used.

Answer (score 0):

If your using InfoPath form and udcx file then you have to change below setting in central admin.

Step1 - Open Central Admin.

Step2 - Open General Application Settings from left panel.

Step3 - Open/Click on Configure InfoPath Forms Services from InfoPath forms Services.

Step4 - Check - Allow embedded SQL authentication checkbox.

Step5 - Check - Allow user form templates to use authentication information contained in data connection files checkbox.

Step6 - Check Allow cross-domain data access for user form templates that use connection settings in a data connection file.